# Referencing other aspx controls events in a module

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

For an ASP.Net application using VB how can I reference an event or textbox not located within the same file.

For example when you are coding on say Default.aspx and you put a textbox on the page this works to reference it.

```
Dim username As String

username = Textbox1.Text
```

Ok but now I want to get the values and response and process it (amongst other tasks) in a separate module say security.vb.

how can I effectively call it from security.vb so it says username = "Default.aspx".Textbox1.Text
i have tried many versions to achieve this and Google'd but I don't know the correct terms to search so am not getting a good result.

The closest Stack question is [Reference from Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286559/accessing-page-controls-events-from-within-a-module) but that doesn't have an answer. I know this must be so simple but it eludes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another "module"? You're not using classes? Using classes would make this easy:

In Default.aspx.vb

```
username = Textbox1.Text
Dim security As New Security(username)
```

In Security.vb:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal username as String)
    Me.username = username
End Sub

Private username as String
```

Then you can access the username variable in your Security class whenever you need it. (Note that since the username variable is not declared as Shared, it will only be valid for the current instance of the Security class that you created in Default.aspx.vb. You could make it Shared, but that would be a bad idea on a web server, since if you did, that would mean that only one user could be logged in at a time, and whenever Bob logs in, Alice's session suddenly starts displaying Bob's data!)

Comment: is there any reason I can't provide 2 arguments to the Dim security statement.  Dim security As New Security(username, password) ?

Comment: No reason at all, apart from the need to edit the constructor (the Sub New) to accept two arguments!